# Hibernate + MSSQL, Cannot insert the value NULL into column

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

Having Hibernate and MSSQL env. I have faced with error:
'Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'comment_id', table 'CHT.dbo.reporter_comments'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.'
Hibernate configuration:

```
<id unsaved-value = "null" type = "int" name="commentId" column="comment_id">
  <generator class="identity"/>
</id>

    <property name="reporterId" column="REPORTERID" />
    <property name="adminComments" column="COMMENT" />
    <property name="commentDate" column="COMMENT_DATE"/>
    <property name="commentBy" column="COMMENT_BY"/>
```

'comment_id' column has 'identity' property in db: if i do insertion using db client:

```
insert into REPORTER_COMMENTS (REPORTERID, COMMENT, COMMENT_DATE, COMMENT_BY) 
values (15119, 'test', '2013-03-04 05:45:25', 'admin');
```

it works perfect for me.

Hibernate logs:

> DEBUG hibernate.SQL - insert into REPORTER_COMMENTS (REPORTERID, COMMENT, COMMENT_DATE, COMMENT_BY) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
>    DEBUG hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - preparing statement
>    DEBUG hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister - Dehydrating entity: [---.ReporterComments#]
>    DEBUG hibernate.type.LongType - binding '15119' to parameter: 1
>    DEBUG hibernate.type.StringType - binding 'test' to parameter: 2
>    DEBUG hibernate.type.TimestampType - binding '2013-03-04 06:13:02' to parameter: 3
>    DEBUG hibernate.type.StringType - binding 'dw' to parameter: 4
>    DEBUG hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
>    DEBUG hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - closing statement
>    DEBUG hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - could not insert: [---.ReporterComments] [insert into REPORTER_COMMENTS (REPORTERID, COMMENT, COMMENT_DATE, COMMENT_BY) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]
>   java.sql.SQLException: [BEA][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'comment_id', table 'CHT.dbo.reporter_comments'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Thanks!

Comment: Since I can't think of any other explanation off the bat, I need to ask; are you absolutely sure that you're connecting to the same database from the Java application as you are from the database client?

Answer (score 4):

Is your `comment_id` column actually an `IDENTITY` column? If it isn't, then that's your problem since Hibernate won't include the `comment_id` column in an insert statement when using an identity generator, relying on the database to generate the value.